# How user associated model like user.user_profile can be updated in devise edit form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have Devise 3.5.6 with normal User model.

I have created another model named `user_profile` with relationship that `user has_one user_profile` and `user_profile belongs_to user`.

UserProfile contains:

```
create_table "user_profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "city"
  t.string   "country"
  t.text     "about"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Now I want the `edit_user_registration_path` to have the form-fields for this model as well and this model gets updated after saving edit form.

This model automatically created with null fields after user is created.

Comment: You can use `nested forms` for this

Comment: Can you please explain how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `User` model you need to write:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_profile
```

If you are using `rails 4` then in the `UsersController` with the other strong parameters add this:

```
params.require(:user).permit(user_profile_attributes: [ :name, :city ])
```

Then in the `form` you need to add this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :user_profile do |user_profile| %>
  <%= user_profile.text_field :name %>
  // The other fields
<% end %>
```

White list all your profile attributes and when you will submit the `user` form it will submit the associated profile attributes too.

There are various gems too when you want to dynamically add fields you can use them:

- [Cocoon Gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon)
- [Nested Form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this was what I needed. Thanks alot